# How to set the target triplet from a crate in Rust for the entire program?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I am exploring ideas for using Rust in a multi-target embedded project.

The current idea I have is to have a crate for every MCU I have. An MCU crate will contain the implementations for things like GPIO, SPI and UART for that specific device.

The system should be designed as such that the MCU crate could be swapped out to the crate of another MCU to target that new MCU. It should also be as easy as possible.

To make that switch right now, you need to also change the .cargo/config file in the executable project from which the build is started yourself. This makes switching a two-step process that at some point will be forgotten about.

Basically, I want the target of the crate to apply to the entire build.

---

I've done some searching around the web to see if it has been before, but either it's not there or my search skills are coming short.

My idea is that a buildscript in the MCU crate could copy its settings to the .cargo/config file of the build instantiator.

---

What I image the buildscript could look like (pseudo):

```
// Open the config file of the directory from which the build is done
dir = build_dir
config_file = open_or_create(dir + .cargo/config)

// Read the target of our own crate
my_target = open(.cargo/config).get_option(option: target)

// Set the target in the config file of the source
config_file.add_or_replace_option(option: target, value: my_target)
```

With something like this, the switch to a different MCU would be very easy. It'd only take changing the dependency in the toml file.

Alternatively, it could be reversed. The executable could have a buildscript that looked for an MCU crate and copied the settings.

---

My questions:

- Is this possible?
- Is this sensible?
- Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: The [Target Specification](https://os.phil-opp.com/minimal-rust-kernel/#target-specification) in phil-opp might help

Answer (score 1):

If your worry is that the config switch is something "that at some point will be forgotten about", you can use some conditional compilation to create an error if the target triple is wrong.

e.g. start the crate `.lib` file with

```rust
#[cfg(not(all(target_arch="...",...)))]
compile_error!("rustc is not correctly configured for this crate - the correct triple is ...");
```

Then switching crates without updating the cargo config will raise an error.

Comment: Thanks, that will help. The main problem I'm concerned with is the ease of switching. This does not help with that, but will help to ensure that a switch was made correctly.